# Namespace/type compiler error

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a C# with a class inside

```
namespace TestBL
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PostedBy { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then add a WebService with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using TestBL;

namespace Test.WebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
         [OperationContract]
         IList<Test> GetTest();
    }
}
```

Everytime I try to use Test class, it returns error:

`'Test' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'`

I fail to see where am I using `Test` as namespace, also my namespace and class name are different.

EDIT: Also, i know I can make it work like

```
IList<TestBL.Test>
```

but I want to konw why am I getting error.

Comment: namespace name and class name must be different in same project

Comment: How is TestBL and Test same name?

Comment: Look at on `Test.WebService`

Comment: `Test.WebService` gives you a namespace `Test` and a subnamespace `WebService`....

Comment: Do you mean compiler recognizes only things before period, so `WebService` there is invisible? And naming it without period`TestWebService` will fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ITestService` interface is in the `Test.WebService` namespace. That means `Test` is a namespace. Yeah I know the namespace's name is `Test.WebService` but the C# compiler splits the namespace name with dots so `Test` is a namespace and WebService is a namespace in `Test`.

When you try to use the `Test` class, the compiler is so stupid that it thinks you are trying to write a namesapce so that's why the error occurs.

Summary:

**The error occurs simply because the compiler thinks that Test is a namespace and in that namespace, there is a namespace called WebService.** Get it? In other words, C# compiler is silly (I'm just kidding)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is namespace Test -

```
 namespace Test.WebService // namepace WebService inside namespace Test.
```

and its also a class -

```
public class Test.
```

The compiler doesnt know which one you ment, change the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a nested namespace Test.WebService, which is equivalent to:

```
namespace Test
{
    namespace WebService
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface ITestService
        {
             [OperationContract]
             IList<Test> GetTest();
        }
    }
}
```

The outer namespace (Test) is causing a naming collision with the class Test.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to add, that as a workaround to this without changing any names, one can simply move `using TestBL` inside the namespace like so:

```
namespace Test.WebService
{
    //other using
    using TestBL;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
         [OperationContract]
         IList<Test> GetTest();
    }
}
```

This will not return the error, as I found out, maybe someone will find this helpful.